# getValues From getRangeList

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script is running very slow because I am retrieving values from many different ranges one by one to apply a specific execution.

I have researched and found out about the getRangeList.

What I would like to do is put in an array all my

```
var 1 = sheet.getRange('A1:B1').getValues()
var 2 = sheet.getRange('A2:B2').getValues()
var 3 = sheet.getRange('A3:B3').getValues()
```

to reduce API calls, like such

```
var array = [1,2,3]
```

and then use

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[2]
```

for specific actions.

Currently this is my code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Meta Awareness Campaign');    
var metacampaignvalues = sheet.getRangeList(['A3:AM3','A4:AM4','A5:AM5','A6:AM6','A7:AM7','A8:AM8','A9:AM9','A10:AM10','A11:AM11','A12:AM12','A13:AM13','A14,AM14','A15:AM15','A16:AM16','A17:AM17','A18:AM18','A19:AM19','A20:AM20']).getRanges().map(range => range.getValues());
```

So I need to use

```
metacampaignvalues[0] = sheet.getRange('A3:M3').getValues()

metacampaignvalues[1] = sheet.getRange('A4:M4').getValues()

metacampaignvalues[2] = sheet.getRange('A5:M5').getValues()
```

etc...

In its current state, my code is receiving an error saying: Exception: Range Not Found.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when I saw your script, `'A14,AM14'` is required to be modified to `'A14:AM14'`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `Exception: Range Not Found.`.

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var metacampaignvalues = sheet.getRangeList(['A3:AM3','A4:AM4','A5:AM5','A6:AM6','A7:AM7','A8:AM8','A9:AM9','A10:AM10','A11:AM11','A12:AM12','A13:AM13','A14,AM14','A15:AM15','A16:AM16','A17:AM17','A18:AM18','A19:AM19','A20:AM20']).getRanges().map(range => range.getValues());
```

#### To:

```
var metacampaignvalues = sheet.getRangeList(['A3:AM3', 'A4:AM4', 'A5:AM5', 'A6:AM6', 'A7:AM7', 'A8:AM8', 'A9:AM9', 'A10:AM10', 'A11:AM11', 'A12:AM12', 'A13:AM13', 'A14:AM14', 'A15:AM15', 'A16:AM16', 'A17:AM17', 'A18:AM18', 'A19:AM19', 'A20:AM20']).getRanges().map(range => range.getValues());
```

- But, in your script, it seems that the row numbersa are continuous numbers. So, how about the following modification?

  ```
    var metacampaignvalues = sheet.getRange('A3:AM20').getValues();
  ```

  - By this modification, for example, `metacampaignvalues[5]` returns the values of `A8:AM8`.

#### Note:

- As another approach, if you want to retrieve the values from non-continuous row numbers like `'A1:C1', 'A3:C3', 'A5:C5'` with low process cost, how about using Sheets API as follows? When you test this script, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.

  ```js
  function sample() {
    const sheetName = 'Meta Awareness Campaign';
    const a1Notations = ['A1:C1', 'A3:C3', 'A5:C5'];
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const ranges = a1Notations.map(e => `'${sheetName}'!${e}`);
    const res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ss.getId(), { ranges }).valueRanges.reduce((o, e) => (o[e.range.split("!")[1]] = e.values, o), {});
    console.log(res);
  }
  ```

  - By this sample script, you can retrieve an object as follows.

    ```json
    {
      "A1:C1":[["A1","B1","C1"]],
      "A3:C3":[["A3","B3","C3"]],
      "A5:C5":[["A5","B5","C5"]]
    }
    ```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your prompt response.  Your answers are all correct. But I have a question, if my ranges are continuous, is "sheet.getRange('A3:AM20').getValues()" along with retrieving them [1],[2],etc... the fastest way ? Or is there a faster way to retrieve them ?

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. If your ranges are continuous, I think that the process cost for retrieving `metacampaignvalues[1]` from `var metacampaignvalues = sheet.getRange('A3:AM20').getValues();` is lower than that for retrieving it from rangeList like `sheet.getRangeList(['A3:AM3', 'A4:AM4', 'A5:AM5',,,]).getRanges().map(range => range.getValues());`. If the ranges are not continuous, I think that Sheets API is useful rather than a method of `getValues` is used in a loop.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you very much for your time and responses.

Comment: I just would like to share a finding with you. When I used metacampaignvalues[1],[2],[3],etc... from var metacampaignvalues = sheet.getRange('A3:AM20').getValues(); The script took more than 20 mins to run. But when I used seperate variables individually like sheet.getRange('A1:AM1').getValues(), sheet.getRange('A2:AM2').getValues(), etc.. It took 5 mins. So it is taking less time to call each row defined by a unique variable, then it is when using sheet.getRange('A3:AM20').getValues() and then retreiving [0],[1],[2],etc... This is very strange.

Comment: @Karim First, I have to apologize that I cannot know your Spreadsheet. and your current whole script from your reply because of my poor English skill. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand the situation of `I just would like to share a finding with you. When I used metacampaignvalues[1],[2],[3],etc... from var metacampaignvalues = sheet.getRange('A3:AM20').getValues(); The script took more than 20 mins to run.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Karim So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating it including the script? By this, I would like to confirm it. But, the goal of this question is to remove the error of `Exception: Range Not Found.`. And, your new issue is different from this question. So, can you post your new issue as a new question? I think that in your new issue, it is required to correctly replicate the issue. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: You are right, this is another question. Sorry for the confusion. Sure no problem, I'll make another question about speeding up the script and I will send you the link. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. I think that your new issue is also important for other users. So, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Of course I understand. I'll share the question with you as soon as I write it. Thank you